# XmlDocument and ReadNode

Tags: c#, .net, xml

OK, I am confused.  I don't see why this does not work.

Given:

```
XmlReader reader = ...; //created by calling routine.
XmlDocument tmpDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode a = tmpDoc.ReadNode(reader);
tmpDoc.AppendChild(a);
var t1 = tmpDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Entity")[0];
XmlNode mainNode = tmpDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Entity");
```

The call to GetElementByTagName works but the call to SelectSingleNode does not.
It returns null.
I have tried other form of selecting nodes and they don't work.
Through the debugger I know the InnerXml is correct and contains something like

```
<Entity>
  <aaa />
</Entity>
```

Also: if I use on the same XML in a file.

```
XmlDocument eDoc = new XmlDocument();
eDoc.Load(fileName);
XmlNode eNode = eDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Entity");
```

It works.

Any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Jim K

Comment: This probably doesn't make a difference but in one sample you have //Entity and in the other /Entity.

Comment: Tried all combinations.  None worked.

Comment: When I'm trying to figure out XPath expressions I use a free tool downloadable here: http://www.bubasoft.net/xpathbuilder/Xpathbuilder2.aspx  (XPath Builder).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this code:

```
String xmlString =
    @"<Entity>
        <aaa />
    </Entity>";

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
{
    XmlDocument tmpDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNode a = tmpDoc.ReadNode(reader);
    tmpDoc.AppendChild(a);
    var t1 = tmpDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Entity")[0];
    XmlNode mainNode = tmpDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Entity");
}
```

And it works both for `GetElementsByTagName` and `SelectSingleNode`.
So my guess will be that your XML is invalid. Maybe you could post the XML that reproduce the problem?

Comment: If the XML was invalid, it would throw an exception and not work inconsistently.

Comment: I also know that the XML is valid. I am in the processes of adding some additional functionality and if I use that and don't go through this addition step, the XML works fine.

Comment: I did just verify that the above code is doing the same thing, so maybe it a bug in the in the frame work.   The only difference is the source of the XML and the fact that I have processing using the reader before this call and I am extracting a sub-portion of XML for special processing.  I am going to write a sub example which is closer to the way I am using it am maybe post that.